# what offline change should be made to the registry in order to change a chipset without reinstalling windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, intel-core-i7, chipset

My motherboard died last week. It was no longer on sold, so I had to buy a new one while keeping all previous hardware *(cpu included)*. The main problem is I had to switch to a different chipset.
I installed windows using the fake efi raid, so I needed to be able to read data again.

After setting up the new hardware, I got a blue screen with INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error, clearly telling the new chipset was the issue.
I remember having a similar problem on vista *(it was migrating a physical  machine manually to Hyper-V)*. I solved it by deleting or modifying some registry key somewhere in HKLM\system, but I completely forgot which ones.

I know a similar question had been asked, however, it was solved in a way very specific to the reader which can't be applied here.
Also, with windows 10, no additionnal drivers should be installed. it's only a configuration problem.

Comment: Use Sysprep; what you want cannot be done by just making changes to the registry

Comment: @Ramhound : it’s wrong. In fact the problems lied in various`ImagePath`keys *(solved that problem)*. I’m also not aware of an offline SysPrep. I just recognize the solution won’t be generic is the chipset /physical ʀᴀɪᴅ controller isn’t manufactured by Intel.

Comment: "HKLM\Software\Intel" if it is an Intel chipset

Comment: @Moab more exactly iastorv and probably atapi.

Comment: @user2284570 I was just pointing you in the right direction, otherwise it would have been an answer not a comment.

Comment: @Moab I already solved my problem myself but didn't wrote an answer. I changed several things before trying so I don't really know what was effective.